# Limit of a sequence of averaged numbers?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let $a_0 = 0$, $a_1 = 1$, and $a_n = \frac{a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}}{2}$ for all $n \ge 2$. Consider $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} a_n$.

Using a quick python script I found that for large $n$ $a_n$ tends to $\frac{2}{3}$. How do I prove this result?

Comment: I suppose there are plenty of such questions!

Comment: I know, it seems obvious, but I couldn't find anything that helped me!

Comment: See also: [Limit of sequence in which each term is defined by the average of preceding two terms](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2276402).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $$-2(a_n-a_{n-1})=a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}.$$
So $$a_n-a_{n-1}={(-\frac{1}{2})}^{n-1}.$$
So $$a_n=\sum_{i=1}^n{(-\frac{1}{2})}^{i-1}.$$
Now you know how to compute the limit.